# Some questions about posts that I've edited

Tags: support, edits

I have some questions about posts that I've edited.

1. How can I get a list of all posts that I've edited?
2. Can I get the count of all posts that I've edited?
3. How can I discard my edited post?

Comment: Please, don't use one post for multiple questions. Also, these are all answered by other, pre-existing posts on Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You'll find these on your activity tab in your profile.
2. Click 'Users' at the top, then 'Editors' on the right, then select 'All' just below that, then filter by your own name on that page.
3. You can't, unless you mean 'delete the post', which you can only do in certain circumstances (always your own answers, only your own questions if there are no upvoted answers).

   You can 'undo' an edit by using the 'rollback' link, which copies the *previous* version of a post back on top as a new edit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your user page > Activity > revisions.
2. It tells you the number of Revisions to the left of "Revisions" on the same page.
3. You can Rollback to a previous version of an edit by clicking on the link that is the relative time that you edited the post when you view the post.

If you are referring to Suggested Edits, exchange "suggestions" for "revisions" above, except for (3) where I don't recall if you can recall a suggested edit when you don't have the rep to edit the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Profile contains all these details.

```
1. How can I get posts that edited by me already ?
```

Go to your profile, select Activity tab, select "suggestions" option. It will show you the edit suggestion you did. you can choose any particular from there.

```
 2. Can I get number of edited post by me until now ?
```

You have edited only 1 post till now. In the "suggestion" option when you click on the "suggested edit" link it will show you the suggestion history, where you can find the total number of edits you done at the botton, along with the user who approved/reject your suggest edit.

```
 3. How can I discard my edited post ?
```

There is a roll back link with every edit you made. Just click on it to discard the modification you did.